# Have there been releases of the Dragon Ball manga per issue in English or only collected editions?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga

Basically, I am looking to purchase physical copies of the original *Dragon Ball* manga (and slowly move forward to *Z* and *Super*).

Have there been official releases of the manga in English or only collected editions (e.g. a whole arc or more than one arcs in a single book)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in VIZ's website, both in digital and paperback: https://www.viz.com/read/manga/dragon-ball-volume-1/product/104

Each volume contains more than ten chapters. Based on my experience reading official translations, it does not necessarily mean that each volume would contain one or two arcs as those can span several volumes. However, if it is an omnibus (meaning several volumes compiled into one), it might be possible and those are also available in the same website: https://www.viz.com/read/manga/dragon-ball-3-in-1-edition-volume-1/product/3197

Comment: I prefer individual official original ones instead of omnibus :)